# mysqli_query return false instead of value

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help

I want my script to run if the mysqli_query returns off
I set value of id=1 to off

But my script does not run. But if i replace if off with false it works fine.

What can be wrong ?

```
 $query3=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM choice WHERE id=1");
 $query4=mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
 if ($query4['choice'] == off) {
    $output = shell_exec('sudo python test1.py');
```

Comment: false means the query failed, and your code didn't bother checking for failure. so it blundered on ahead with invalid data. as well, `off` is a constant. is that defined? or should it be a string `'off'`?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend: look again. it is mysqli.

Comment: Unless `off` is a constant, it should be `$off`. Also, If `off` is not a variable/constant and you are trying to check for string equality, you should use `strcmp` function.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this isn't a MySQL problem, try this:

```
 if (strcmp($query4['choice'], 'off') == 0) {
    $output = shell_exec('sudo python test1.py');
 }
```

Or even:

```
 if ($query4['choice'] === 'off') {
    $output = shell_exec('sudo python test1.py');
 }
```

In the first example, we are comparing the string for equality, if zero is returned, there is no difference, meaning the strings are identical in every way.

In the second example, we are checking for type with the triple equal sign `===`, so it will compare string to string properly as well.

Comment: Why would you use `strcmp` here instead of `==`?

Comment: I think you're barking up the completely wrong tree here unless you can explain what you're intending with the completely convoluted `strcmp` call or the pointless `===` comparison.

Comment: These kinds of problems are common beginner problems and may very well be the answer the OP was looking for. I would wait for the OP feedback before assuming I am incorrectly tackling this question.

Comment: As a sidenote, the downvote is completely uncalled for and you calling a simple `strcmp` convoluted or `===` pointless does not compliment your intelligence in any way.

Comment: Unless you're writing C code, `strcmp(...) == 0` is needless clutter and irrelevant unless you're concerned about sort order. `===` should be the only thing you're talking about here if you're concerned about avoiding automatic casting, something you don't mention. I downvoted because this answer will confuse anyone trying to solve this problem, but you can fix that.

Comment: strcmp() is a built-in function available in the **latest** version of PHP. It being 'convoluted' or 'useless clutter' is strictly a matter of personal preference that I and many others would disagree with. Note, you cannot compare two strings for equality using a case insensitive check using `===`, you can with `stricmp`.

Comment: Also, rather than spending so much time bashing my response, you should answer the OP question and include anything you see fit, i.e. automatic casting.

Comment: Instead of getting agitated here, you should include such relevant details in your answer. You asked why I down voted, and I'm just explaining. I think this is a low-quality answer, but it could be improved.

Comment: I tried === still the same. My database is working switches on and off id1. But how do i get value: on or off.? I need a if statement. Where it get on or off out of the database. Table is choice and id1 is set to on when on and off when off